# AngularJS ng-options Ajax default selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

How can I set a default value based on ajax results in ng-options?

```
<select ng-model="model.stuff" ng-options="o.name for o in options track by o.id"></select>
```

Then in my controller I have

```
$http.get("myurl").then(
    // On Success
    function(response) {
        $scope.options = response.data;
    },
    // On Error
    function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR");
    }
);
```

Example data would be this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bar"
  }
]
```

This get is triggered when other stuff in my controller is activated, my select list fills correctly, with all my options.

But sometimes I need to set a default value after loading ajax data. For example I need to load `id 1` from my data array.

This doesn't mean to load `response.data[1]` this means that I have to search inside  `response.data` and look for an item that has `id: 1`. This works with this method

```
function getArrayIndex(key, source){
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (source[i].id == key) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This will tell me that `response.data[0]` has `id: 1` so I want to use that as my default selected value when ajax loads my data.

How can I achieve that?

I've read some other questions but I got nothing working... I've tried setting `ng-init` with the `id` value and with an entire `object` but doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to add the following to your controller.

```
$scope.model = { stuff: null };

$scope.$watch('options', function() {
  if ($scope.options) {
    $scope.model.stuff = $scope.options[0].name;
  }
});
```

To match your example, set $scope.model as an object with a key of 'stuff'. The $watch will fire when the $scope object 'options' changes. The 'if' statement ensures no error occurs if 'options' is ever set to null.

Refer to the [$scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for more information on $watch